# Trouble with assigning a model's own mesh to a mesh collider in Unity

Tags: unity, collision-detection, meshcollider, collider

I'm trying to use a mesh collider on the player's avatar, rather than the box collider.

I've added the mesh collider to the game object (which also has a rigid body) and selected the "convex" checkbox.  However, the player still falls through all geometry, including Unity primitives, terrain, and other models.

In the mesh collider's property box, there's a value for "Mesh", which I have set to "None (Mesh)".  I was led to believe this defaults to the model's own mesh, but now I'm not certain.  If I change the value to something else from the "select mesh" list, like the cube, the collisions work.  When I click over to Select Mesh --> Scene, the list is empty.  I'm assuming I need to add the model's mesh to the list, but I can't find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 1):

Did some trial and error.

**The mesh collider has to be added to the actual mesh object, not the game object that contains the mesh**.

For example, if you have player_car, which contains a car_mesh, a camera, and whatever else you need, then the mesh collider has to be added to car_mesh and not player_car.

If you created your object by dragging the model into the scene, then the game object and mesh object likely are one and the same.  However, if you needed to create a more elaborate hierarchy (like I did), then you'll need to be more careful about where the collider goes.

Apparently a box collider can just be put any old place since the dimensions are user-defined.